# Can't run the Nginx executable file

Tags: windows, nginx

I've installed Nginx web server on my machine under Windows 7 with php.

When I start the "nginx.exe", the command prompt opens for a second and then closes automatically, so I can't control it through the command prompt. Couldn't find a solution anywhere.

What I want is to open the "nginx.exe" and use various commands there.

Otherwise the server is working.

Comment: Same for me on windows 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First you need to know the path to your nginx.exe file.
2. Once you have that right click on your desktop and click on the new text document.
3. Then type or paste in the following text:

> ```
> c:\
> cd c:\nginx
> start nginx.exe
> cmd /k
> ```

4. Now save the file with whatever name you want to use but add the .bat extension to it.  Example nginx.bat
5. Now you can click on the file and it should open the  command prompt, change the directory, start the server, and then leave the prompt open in the correct directory so you can run your commands.

Comment: The path is the same as your suggested. But when I paste the text (/K "C:\nginx\nginx.exe") and click on the "next" button, I get:
"The file /K cannot be found"...

Comment: Try manually typing the quotation marks sometimes pasting messes them up

Comment: Oh and the cmd is part of the path

Comment: path    ->         cmd /K "C:\nginx\nginx.exe"

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But when I open it I get this (after which I can't type nginx commands):



nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "logs/error.log" fail
ed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2015/08/21 12:15:27 [emerg] 6216#7296: CreateFile() "C:\Windows\system32/conf/ng
inx.conf" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Check out my new solution when you get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

I made a different version of the script of Larry Lane.
With this version you can **invoke nginx from any path**.

The script needs to be in any route accessible via Windows path and should be named *nginx.bat*.

```
@echo off
SET var=%cd%
cd C:/nginx
nginx %*
cd %var%
```

Execution example:

[image: Execution example]